# Horizontally align & center 3 equal divs

Tags: html, css

So normally, when I need to align 3 divs, i'd go with this solution:

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
```

but in this case, I don't wanna do that. Now I have 1 class, `.medew` which I need to show in a container three times. These three should be aligned in the center. I've tried what I knew, but my knowledge is letting me down again.

This is the css I'm currently using:

```
.medew {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    background-position: 5px 0px;
    color: #313131;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 8px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #B2B2B2;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 150px;
    min-height: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Is there any way to have three of those divs that are horizontally aligned and centered in a parent container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply center a parent container with `margin: 0 auto` and set all three inner containers to `display: inline-block` with a certain width!

CSS

```
.parent {
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
}

.inner {
background-color: #D3D3D3;
width: 150px;
min-height: 45px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="inner"></div>
   <div class="inner"></div>
   <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Of course you can use all the other CSS style options along with this!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this might be using flexbox like this: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lunaetic/a2efzbpt/1/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="medew"></div>
    <div class="medew"></div>
    <div class="medew"></div>
</div>

.medew {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    background-position: 5px 0px;
    color: #313131;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 8px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #B2B2B2;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 150px;
    min-height: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a38dofr3/)**

```
.container {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}
.medew {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;       
    color: #313131;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 8px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #B2B2B2;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 150px;
    min-height: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="medew"></div>
    <div class="medew"></div>
    <div class="medew"></div>
</div>
```