# How to align and center two divs horizontally and also to make them responsive?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I should do it like on this picture. The two fields should be horizontally aligned and flexible. I think that these fields should be two divs in one mother div?

```css
.parentField {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
}

.field1 {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.field2 {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.browse {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: -500%;
  margin-left: 80%;
  margin-top: -500%;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 14px;
  font-size: small;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.or {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.text1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 14px;
  font-size: small;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.browse1 {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentField">
  <div class="field1">
    <p class="text">Upload a Power Point presentation .pptx .pptm .ppt</p>
    <button class="browse">Browse</button>
  </div>
  <p class="or">or</p>
  <div class="field2">
    <p class="text1">Upload a Word document .doc .docm .docx</p>
    <button class="browse1">Browse</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your code, We will fix it.

Comment: I posted it! Can you see how it should looks in the image?

Comment: Please add that directly to the question, not as a comment or an answer.

Comment: Should I upload and the CSS also?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: Done! It is urgent task, I will be happy if someone can help me to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Horizontally align & center 3 equal divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30478531/horizontally-align-center-3-equal-divs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox for this one.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.separator {
  text-align: center;
  padding-inline-end: 5px;
  padding-inline-start: 5px;
}

.file-upload{
  padding-inline-end: 5px;
  padding-inline-start: 5px;
}

.form-control {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.44444444;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="file-upload">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="first element..." />
  </div>
  <div class="separator">
    <p>or</p>
  </div>
  <div class="file-upload">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="second element..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

You can play with `justify-content` property to find your desired outcome. Also note that `justify-content` changes element position on the "main" axis. With the property `flex-direction` which default value is row, you can determine the main axis. So here the main axis is x, and in order to change the elements' position vertically, you should set the `align-items` property.

The best reference for flexbox I've found is here:  [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parentField {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

.field {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.browse {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.text {
  font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentField">
      <div class="field">
        <p class="text">Upload a Power Point presentation .pptx .pptm .ppt</p>
        <button class="browse">Browse</button>
      </div>
      <p class="or">or</p>
      <div class="field">
        <p class="text">Upload a Word document .doc .docm .docx</p>
        <button class="browse">Browse</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexbox in order to achieve your desired output. You can refer to my CSS to achieve the same as shown in Screen Shot you shared.
Also, You cannot directly style `<input type="file"`, so instead you can hide it and use the custom button to achieve the same. But to use the custom button you'll need to add the `JavaScript` function as I have used the below code which points to `<input type="file"` on the click custom button.

```js
document.getElementById('buttonid').addEventListener('click', openDialog);

function openDialog() {
  document.getElementById('fileid').click();
}
```

```css
.parentField {
    width: 80%;
    font-family: calibri;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.field1 {
    display: flex;
    border: 2px dotted grey;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

.text {
    margin: 0px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: grey;
}

#buttonid {
    margin: 5px 7px 5px 20px;
    background: #4E6844;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;

}

img {
    height: 35px;
}

span{
  margin:0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentField">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="field1">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/48/null/microsoft-powerpoint-2019.png" />
      <p class="text">Upload a Power Point presentation .pptx .pptm .ppt</p>
      <input id='fileid' type='file' hidden />
      <span id='buttonid' value='Browse'>Browse</span>
    </div>
    <span>or</span>
    <div class="field1">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/48/null/microsoft-word-2019.png" />
      <p class="text">Upload a Power Point presentation .pptx .pptm .ppt</p>
      <input id='fileid' type='file' hidden />
      <span id='buttonid' value='Browse'>Browse</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```